# Creating a list between two date intervals in Angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript

Title more or less sums it up. I'm actually here for the logic: I have a list which has too much items in it and therefore needs to be shortened in this way.

Let's say that I have 2 intervals, 1 starting from today and going back 6months in time, the other one is 6 months ahead in time. I want the items to be listed between these dates: 08-01-2021 until 10-12-2022

P.S. Items have a date object in it so I can cherry-pick them this way.

What would you suggest, and why?

Comment: So each date has one item associated with it ?

Comment: lets say it is: 
{
     name: 'Something',
     date: '2022-06-03'
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood the question correctly but maybe this way:

```
let start = new Date("08-01-2021");
let end   = new Date("10-12-2022");
let newList = [];

makeNewList(){
   oldList.filter(item => {
   (item.date >= start && item.date <= end;) ? newList.push(item.name) : console.log("Didn't match!");
}
}
```